# Fully clickable Ajax-Button with RichFaces and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, richfaces

I'm trying to have a fully-clickable span or Button with a Bootstrap refresh glyph-icon. With the code I've inherited, the icon itself is clickable, but the area between icon and button border isn't, i.e., it feels to the user as if clicking on the edge of the button doesn't work.

Here is the current code:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <h:commandLink  id="refresh" style="height:25px">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>       
        <a4j:ajax render="richTable cnt_label scroller"
          execute="richTable cnt_label scroller" event="click" immediate="true"
          oncomplete="richTableRerenderCompleted('refresh')"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</span>
```

I've tryed replacing the outer span with a `<button>` and that seemed to do the trick, but it warps the table in a funny way while refreshing.

Using a RichFaces commandButton or commandLink directly made everything worse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the icon is just a letter you can create a button and put the icon in the label.

If you inspect the span you should see something like this:

```
<span …>
    ::before
</span>
```

Then check the CSS for `::before` and you should see:

```
.glyphicon-refresh:before {
    content: "\e031";
}
```

`e031` is the number of letter, you can convert it to an HTML entity and do this:

```
<h:commandButton value="&#xe031;" styleClass="btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon">
```

Comment: That's a great idea, but I only get an undisplayable symbol

Comment: I tested it right on the bootstrap page (with a <span>), it has to work. Check if the font-family isn't being overwritten.

Comment: Weird, tried it again and it worked. Maybe because I put the value attribute after the style(class) attribute(s). Although I thought that that shouldn't matter. Anyways, it works! Ty

Comment: Ah wait, now I see why. I tried it with a commandButton last time, but I forgot to change that, so it was still a commandLink. But works and looks fine. I haven't checked the generated Markup, but I guess that's where the problem lies (for anyone else having that problem)